# The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm: Why evaluation order is important?

Tags: javascript, types, ecmascript-5, coercion, type-coercion

When I read EcmaScript spesification in The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm part have information about "LeftFirst" parameter and also spesification say evauation order is not important primitive type but important Object type.
Anyone can explain me what is difference which object first evaluated?

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5
Ecmascript Spesification (aka ecma-internation.org) section 11.8.5 (The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm)

Comment: Please add a link to the article/docs you are referring to.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: New question pleas look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260084/the-less-than-or-equal-operator-with-nan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm evaluates `x < y`, but it is used for several operators, E.G. `x < y`, `x > y`, `x >= y`, sometimes by flipping the order of the operands. In the case of `x > y`, the [spec for the Greater-than operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.2) says:

> Let r be the result of performing abstract relational comparison rval < lval with LeftFirst equal to false.

LeftFirst doesn't matter for primitives because there are no side-effects when they are coerced to numbers for the comparison. However, for objects there can be side-effects:

```js
const x = { valueOf: _ => console.log( 'x' ) };
const y = { valueOf: _ => console.log( 'y' ) };

y > x;
```

The above code logs `y` then `x`. Since it uses the greater-than operator, it uses the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm for `x < y` with `LeftFirst = false` as per the above quote from the spec. If instead it used the same algorithm, but with `LeftFirst = true`, then it would end up calling ToPrimitive on `x` before calling ToPrimitive on `y`, which would cause `x` to be logged before `y`.

Comment: Great Answer! 
Thank You Very Much :)

Comment: I think You can answer this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260084/the-less-than-or-equal-operator-with-nan