# The Less-than-or-equal Operator: With NaN

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, ecmascript-5, type-coercion

When we use The Less-than-or-equal Operator this is work under the hood with The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm.
For example.

```
a <= b;
```

Convert to JavaScript like this

```
!(b < a)
```

And EcmaScript Spesification says (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) which indicates that at least one operand is NaN less than return undefined 
And this is meaning

```
var a = 1;
var b = "asd"
a < b // b.toNumber() => NaN and this is operation return undefined (false)
```

If we use like this

```
var a = 1;
var b = "asd"
a <= b // this convert to  !(b < a) and (b<a) return undefined
// and !(undefined) must be true
```

But EcmaScript spesification says this is return false. This is interesting for me what is reason this?

Comment: Have a closer look at [step 6 of the Less-than-or-equal Operator (`<=`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.3): "*If `r` is `true` **or `undefined`**, return `false`. Otherwise, return `true`.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While <= does use the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm, `a <= b` isn't equivalent to `!(b < a)`. It is equivalent to `b < a !== false ? false : true` (where `<` represents the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm, not the JavaScript `<` operator which can never evaluate to `undefined`), which behaves the same as `!(b < a)` when `b < a` is truthy or exactly `false`, but does not behave the same when `b < a` is falsey in general. If `b < a` evaluates to `undefined`, the whole expression will evaluate to `false`.

This is defined in the spec at step 6 here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.3

> 5. Let *r* be the result of performing abstract relational comparison
>      *rval* < *lval* with *LeftFirst* equal to **false**.
> 6. If *r* is **true** or **undefined**, return **false**. Otherwise, return **true**.

The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm can only evaluate to `true`, `false`, or `undefined`; so the "Otherwise" in step 6 can only apply when `r` is `false`, making `a <= b` equivalent to `b < a !== false ? false : true` (again, where `<` represents the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm).

Comment: Thank You Verry Much :) I learn under the hood JavaScript with You :d