# Safe to assume undefined will always evaluate as false when used with the < or > operator?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Let's say you have a deactivation date field. If the field is not defined, then the entity is active. If the field is defined, then we compare the deactivation date to the current date. We might express the logic as such.

```
const isInactive = entity.deactivationDate && entity.deactivationDate < currentDate;
```

However, is checking if `deactivationDate` is defined necessary? With JS, it seems that when using `undefined` with the `<` or `>` operator, the resulting expression will always evaluate as false. Is it safe to use the following logic?

```
const isInactive = entity.deactivationDate < currentDate;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than - `undefined` is converted to `NaN`, which then compares as `false`

Comment: @RaymondChen You can post that as an answer if you want. That is the perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Less-than-or-equal Operator: With NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260084/the-less-than-or-equal-operator-with-nan)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, you might be able to extrapolate the answer from that question, but Raymond's answer was much more apparent to me.

Comment: Note that `<`, `==`, and `>` will all be false when used with `undefined` or `NaN`. And it doesn't matter what order the operands are: `x < undefined` and `undefined < x` are both false.

Comment: While this result is specified, I don't recommend depending on it, it makes your coding more confusing. Be explicit about converting an undefined value to a default -- you can use the `??` operator for this.

Comment: @Barmar are you suggesting something like this?
`const isInactive = (entity.deactivationDate ?? '9999-99-99') < currentDate;`

Comment: That doesn't work, either. `NaN ?? 'something'` is `NaN`. You have to use `const isInactive = isNaN(entity.deactivationDate) ? false : (entity.deactivationDate ?? '9999-99-99') < currentDate;`